# Calculating multiple ROC curves in R using a for loop and pROC package. What variable to use in the predictor field?

Tags: r, for-loop, roc, proc-r-package

I am using the pROC package and I want to calculate multiple ROC curve plots using a for loop.
My variables are specific column names that are included as string in a vector and I want pROC to read sequentially that vector and use the strings in the field "predictor" that seems to accept text/characters.
However, I cannot parse correctly the variable, as I am getting the error:

> 'predictor' argument should be the name of the column, optionally quoted.

here is an example code with aSAH dataset:

```
ROCvector<- c("s100b","ndka")
for (i in seq_along(ROCvector)){
  a<-ROCvector[i]
pROC_obj <- roc(data=aSAH, outcome, as.character(a))

#code for output/print#

}
```

I have tried to call just "a" and using the functions print() or get() without any results.
Writing manually the variable (with or without quoting) works, of course.
Is there something I am missing about the type of variable I should use in the predictor field?

Comment: I see where you are coming from. I should be able to improve the error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By passing `data=aSAH` as first argument, you are triggering the [non-standard evaluation (NSE) of arguments, dplyr-style](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html). Therefore you cannot simply pass the column name in a variable. Note the inconsistency with `outcome` that you pass unquoted and looks like a variable (but isn't)? Fortunately, [functions with NSE in dplyr come with an equivalent function with standard evaluation, whose name ends with `_`](https://www.r-bloggers.com/non-standard-evaluation-and-standard-evaluation-in-dplyr/). The pROC package follows this convention. You should usually use those if you are programming with column names.

Long story short, you should use the `roc_` function instead, which accepts characters as column names (don't forget to quote `"outcome"`):

```
pROC_obj <- roc_(data=aSAH, "outcome", as.character(a))
```

A slightly more idiomatic version of your code would be:

```
for (predictor in ROCvector) {
    pROC_obj <- roc_(data=aSAH, "outcome", predictor)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and for pointing out the inconsistency. Invoking the other function worked and the code is cleaner and more readable.

Answer (score 1):

`roc` can accept *formula*, so we can use `paste0` and `as.formula` to create one. i.e.

```
library(pROC)
ROCvector<- c("s100b","ndka")
for (i in seq_along(ROCvector)){
    a<-ROCvector[i]
    pROC_obj <- roc(as.formula(paste0("outcome~",a)), data=aSAH)
    print(pROC_obj)
    #code for output/print#

}
```

To can get the original call i.e. without `paste0` wich you can use for later for downstream calculations, use `eval` and `bquote`

```
pROC_obj <- eval(bquote(roc(.(as.formula(paste0("outcome~",a))), data=aSAH)))
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked, and i've learned something about formulas.